# Bot de trading utilizando Ichimoku Cloud y EMA con trail stop, resolver advertencias sobre inconsistencia de funciones highest y lowest

Tags: algoritmos, lógica, pine-script

En el canal de Youtube del investigador Andrés Aristizábal se publicó la forma de hacer indicadores utlizando nubes de Ichimoku y EMA, posteriormente quise modificar el ejemplo pulicado para que ejecute ordenes de compra y venta con rutinas de trailing stop y el marcado de las posiciones de compra y venta. El caso es que ahora no ocurre una sola entrada. Reconozco que soy nuevo en programación en Pine Script v5, pero quisiera saber si hay otra manera de hacerlo más simple como la estrategia original.
Tengo entendido que las funciones highest y lowest no se podrían ejecutar dentro de sus respectivos condicionales.

Aquí el video publicado por Andrés Aristizábal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FYBgH59V1Y

Funcionaría mejor si sólo dejo dentro de sus respectivos condicionales a las entradas en largo o en corto y todo lo demás queda fuera?

Gracias por su ayuda y espero que les sirva el código.

A continuación dejo el código en cuestión y las advertencias.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Ichimoku Cloud Strategy EMA Exec", shorttitle="IchiCldStrtHAshJRBx", overlay=true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100)
conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")
trail_offset = input.float(defval=0.0, title="Trail Offset")
trail_percent = input.float(defval=0.0, title="Trail Percent")
trail_points = input.float(defval=0.0, title="Trail Points")

donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

LongCond = close > conversionLine and close > baseLine and close > leadLine1 and close > leadLine2 and close > ta.ema(close, 180)
ShortCond = close < conversionLine and close < baseLine and close < leadLine1 and close < leadLine2 and close < ta.ema(close, 180)

if LongCond
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

    longStopPrice = ta.highest(high, int(trail_percent)) * (1 - trail_offset / 100)
    longExitPrice = math.max(close, longStopPrice)

    strategy.exit("Long", "Long TP/SL", trail_points = trail_points, trail_offset = trail_offset, stop = longStopPrice, limit = longExitPrice)
plotshape(LongCond, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.green,0))

if ShortCond
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

    shortStopPrice = ta.lowest(low, int(trail_percent)) * (1 + trail_offset / 100)
    shortExitPrice = math.min(close, shortStopPrice)

    strategy.exit("Short", "Short TP/SL", trail_points = trail_points, trail_offset = trail_offset, stop = shortStopPrice, limit = shortExitPrice)
plotshape(ShortCond, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red,0))

plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")
p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7,
     title="Leading Span A")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A,
     title="Leading Span B")
plot(leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1,
     title="Kumo Cloud Upper Line", display=display.none) 
plot(leadLine1 < leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2,
     offset=displacement - 1,
     title="Kumo Cloud Lower Line",
     display=display.none) 
fill(p1, p2, color=leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))
```

14:50:39    Aviso en 23:21 The function 'ta.highest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
14:50:39    Aviso en 32:22 The function 'ta.lowest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas algo simple, podes usar *Base Line* como Trailing Stop
Algo así:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("Long TP/SL", "Long", stop = baseLine)
```